# SQL missing first value when there is more than 1 value in table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function in php that allows the user to input information and add it into a database of sql. It seems that my very first value is always missing when more of the data is added. The very last value seems to be shifted down so that there isn't even any values there. Here is the code:

```
$firstname = $_POST['Fname'];
$lastname = $_POST['Lname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$gender = $_POST['Gender'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$condition = $_POST ['condition'];

if ($condition == 'add')
{
$SQL = "INSERT INTO People (Last_Name, First_Name, Age, Gender, Email, Cityid)
        VALUES ('$lastname', '$firstname', '$age', '$gender', '$email',    '$city')";
    $result=mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());

}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<form action = 'Project 5 Page 2.php' Method = 'POST'>
<center>
First Name <input type = 'text' maxlength = '20' name = 'Fname'>
<br>
Last Name <input type = 'text' maxlength = '20' name = 'Lname'> 
<br>
Email <input type = 'text' maxlength = '100' name = 'email'>

<br>
Male <input type = 'radio' name = 'Gender' value = 'Male'>
Female <input type = 'radio' name = 'Gender' value = 'Female'>
<br>
Age <Select name = 'age' value = 'agename'>
<option value = 'agevalue'>Select</option>
<?php
for ($i=0;$i<121;$i++)
{
    echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<br>

<?php
$SQL="SELECT * from cities ORDER BY province ASC"; 
$result=mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());
$num_results=mysql_num_rows($result);
mysql_close($db);
?>

City <select name = 'city' value = 'citychoose'>
<option value = 'citychoice'>Select</option>

<?php
for ($c=0;$c<$num_results;$c++) 
{
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['name'].", ".$row['province']."    </option>";
}
?>  

</select>
<br>
Add <input type = 'radio' name = 'condition' value = 'add'>
Edit <input type = 'radio' name = 'condition' value = 'Edit'>
Delete <input type = 'radio' name = 'condition' value = 'Delete'>
<br>
<input type="submit" value = Submit>
```

Comment: can we see your html form?

Comment: [Bobby Tables is having a field day again](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: What's your SQL SELECT statement that suggests you're missing rows?

Comment: While we're waiting on the HTML, I'd like to go ahead and point out two major flaws. One is that mysql_* is deprecated and you should remove it. The other is the massive SQL injection vulnerability you have.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes, that's one of my favorites!

Comment: @r3mus when I try to display all the information in a for loop it does not display the first rows.

Comment: @MarioSegura the HTML is up

Comment: @Zarazthuztra Sorry, beginner at coding and using this site. Also, HTML form is up.

Comment: if mysql_close($db) actually closes the data connection, $result will no longer be valid and should return no rows.

Comment: You could do this a lot easier with `mysql_fetch_assoc`, then `for ($row in $results)`